# error when running brew install elasticsearch and installing Java 1.7 on Yosemite

Tags: java, homebrew

I'm trying to run

```
brew install elasticsearch
```

I keep getting this error

```
elasticsearch: Java 1.7+ is required to install this formula.
You can install with Homebrew Cask:
  brew install Caskroom/cask/java

You can download from:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

I've run brew doctor, brew update, brew cleanup ect... and still keep getting this error. It appears it has something to do with a bug in Yosemite.

When I run

```
 brew install Caskroom/cask/java
```

It says it's already installed. What give!

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

Install Java Mac

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
brew install brew-cask
brew cask install java
```

Install ES

```
brew update
brew install elasticsearch
brew info elasticsearch
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I just figured it out, I tried all of those things plus I updated my java here. https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US  I followed the steps outlined here https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting and it If you add that to your answer I'll mark it correct as I did all of those things too.

Comment: Note that Homebrew now makes it easier to install casks, you can just run `brew cask install java` and it’ll automatically run `brew tap caskroom/cask` and install `brew-cask` for you.